# What is the lifespan of [lifespan]?

Tags: discussion

Subject says it all. Just posted a question and noticed the [lifespan](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/lifespan) tag. So I understand the spirit of the tag, but it has no summary and seems very broad. And might also encourage questions that are extremely localized in scope.

So what’s the lifespan of [lifespan](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/lifespan)?

[image: GIF from “Logan’s Run” of Logan’s life clock blinking.]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are mixed arguments for this tag.  I agree that it seems broad and is pretty meta.  However:

- Lifespan "is a thing", and even though it can be applied to a lot of different stuff, I think hardware life questions do share a common knowledge base and are likely to be answered by largely the same segment of readers.
- It makes a useful subject area tag for readers, answerers, and searches.

Personal opinion: let [lifespan](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/lifespan) live long and prosper.